# elastic search in .net with NEST

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio, elasticsearch, nest

I am trying to get ElasticSearch data with NEST in ASP.NET. With a Button that when its clicked my data will be shown in a TextBox.
Do I need to put my database in the project or something? , when I click the button no data is shown.

I am using Visual Studio 2015, .NET Framework 4.6.1

I am a beginner so I can't handle this error that occurred.
I will provide my code.

**Error:**
[image]

NuGet Packages:
[image]

```
namespace ElasticsearchWeb{
public class shekspir
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public int line_id { get; set; }
    public string play_name { get; set; }
    public int speech_number { get; set; }
    public float line_number { get; set; }
    public string speaker { get; set; }
    public string text_entry { get; set; }
}
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public static Uri GetElasticHost()
    {
        var host = "http://localhost:9200";
        return new Uri(host);
    }
    public static ElasticClient GetElasticClient(ConnectionSettings settings = null)
    {
        if (settings == null)
        {
            var node = GetElasticHost();
            var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(node);
            settings = new ConnectionSettings(pool);
        }
        settings.DisableDirectStreaming(true);
        var client = new ElasticClient(settings);
        return client;
    }

    public static List<shekspir> GetAllShekspir(int ID)
    {
        var client = GetElasticClient();

        ISearchResponse<shekspir> result = null;

        result = client.Search<shekspir>(x => x
        .Index("shekspir")
        .Query(q => q
            .MatchAll())

        );

        List<shekspir> list = new List<shekspir>();
        foreach (var r in result.Hits)
        {
            shekspir a = r.Source;
            list.Add(a);
        }

        return list;
    }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        List<shekspir> list = GetAllShekspir(1);

        foreach (shekspir u in list)
        {
            litInfo.Text += u.play_name + ": " + u.text_entry + "<br>";


        }

    }
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

What version of .Net runtime is your application running? The elastic search Nest API version that you have used is expecting the .Net Standard Version 2.0, which it cannot find.